# Permutation Lines,i want to give it different values when i select check boxes

Tags: javascript

Please I am working on a football pools website. I am having problems with my permutation lines, I have a checkbox, where  added a counter which automatically displays the number of selected lines, which starts from 3. I want it to display 4 lines when I select 4 check boxes, and 10 lines when I select 5. Can any one help me out. I have tried using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkcontrol(j) {
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0; i < document.form1.match.length; i++){
        if(document.form1.match[i].checked)
            total =total +1+0.1;
        if(total == 49){
            console.write("") 
            document.form1.match[j].checked = true ;
            return true;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result3").value = "" + total.toFixed(0);
}
</script>
```